# Find principal components of $(X_1,X_2,X_1+X_2)$

Tags: pca, linear-algebra

I need to find the principal components of $(X_1,X_2,X_1+X_2)$ and the proportion of variance the first principal component explains. No information about the distribution or independence of the $X_i$ is given.
If we denote $v_1= Var(X_1)$, $v_2=Var(X_2)$ and $c=Cov(X_1,X_2)$, then the variance-covariance matrix is given by
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1&c& v_1+c\\ c & v_2 & v_2 +c \\ v_1+c & v_2 +c & v_1+v_2+2c
\end{pmatrix}
Calculating the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix takes some effort. Is there a smarter way to calculate the principal components?

Comment: The best you can do is observe that (obviously) one eigenvalue is zero, thereby reducing the problem to solving a quadratic equation.  That quadratic does not simplify in general.